# php download script not work with ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

Tags: php, download

i always start index.php with `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");` and end it with `ob_flush();`

i use [HTTP Download](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2221-PHP-Server-files-for-downloading-with-resume-support.html) for download files in my filemanager and it works perfectly, but if download request started with `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");` in index.php it did not work.

i clean and turn off output buffering before download script

```
ini_set('zlib.output_compression','Off');
ob_end_clean();
```

but still user can't download files

Comment: does your PHP have `zlib` extension installed and enabled ? double check with `phpinfo()`. do not suppress the error by leading `@` to view the error.

Comment: yes zlib extension is installed and enabled .

Comment: In PHP documentation, it said enabling `zlib.output_compression` is more preferred than `ob_gzhandler`. Why do you want to use it ?

Comment: yes,I think the problem is browser hanging until finished download file and then immediately save it.